# How to combine multiple http requests and database query with Rxjava on Android

Tags: android, rx-java

I need to perform multiple http requests and a database query in order to filter data.

I am usin the zip operator from Rxjava

I did the following to prepare my multiple http requests

```
 List<Observable<List<Picture>>> requests = new ArrayList<>();


 for(String id : photoIds) {
    requests.add(pictureRepository.searchPicture(id).toObservable());
 }
```

I did the following to prepare my database request

```
Observable<List<Favourite>> favourites = pictureRepository.getFavourites().toObservable();
```

I try to create the observable but rxjava is not accepting my code

```
Observable.zip(
        requests, favourites,
        new BiFunction<Object[], List<Favourite>, List<FavouritePictures>>() {
            @Override
            public List<FavouritePictures> apply(Object[] t1, List<Favourite> t2) throws Exception {
                return /*here I want to check the favourites and return a list*/;
            }
        }
);
```

Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please specify how your result should look like? How many List<Favourite> will be emitted by favourites? Do you want to combine each favourite emit with each List<Picture> emit or do want to combine the latest favourite emite with the latest List<Picture>?

Comment: My result should be the list of pictures where the pictures that are marked as favourite in the database should have the field "favourite" marked as true. In other words I want to mark the favourite pictures but still show the ones that are not favourites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that may work for this is the following:

```
val photoIds = listOf(1, 2, 3)
var index = 0

Observable.just(0).flatMapSingle {
        pictureRepository.searchPicture(photoIds[index])
        index += 1
    }.repeatUntil {
        index + 1 == photoIds.size - 1
    }.toList().zipWith(pictureRepository.getFavourites(),
         BiFunction { listOfPictures, listOfFavoratePictures ->
             // Return your list
         })
```

1. This observable stream will start by emitting 0;
2. Then it will flatMap the stream to a Single Observable and return the observable stream from the searchPicture call;
3. This process will be continued until the last item index has been reached;
4. Then we map the result to be emitted as one list;
5. Finally we zip the Single Observable with the getFavourites call;

You could also achieve this using a recursive method but I personally find this more readable.